# Как слить продакшн с девелоп логично, git-правильно и чисто?

Tags: git, развертывание

Всем, привет!

С чего все началось...есть проект - сайт, на локальном сервере, задуман перенос в сеть.  Создан локальный репозиторий, в нем две ветки master (продакшн) и develop (разработка).

Если по шагам, то вот. Создан локально репозиторий, в нем сделан первый коммит, он же инициализация проекта, все это ветка продакшн (master), в коммит включены файлы .gitignore и исключены файлы необходимые для разработки (директория с less-файлами, js-исходники и т.д.). Т.е. ветка продакшн подготовлена к push-у в удаленный репозиторий (origin/master).

После того как был сделан вышеописанный первый коммит, создается ветка develop (разработка). Ветка настраивается для разработки, т.е. изменяются файлы .gitignore, включаются в индекс файлы разработки .less, js-исходники и тому подобные.

Я рассудил, что делаю все правильно...если не одно но..жирное НО...

Например, создаю временную ветку release (релизная ветка), делаю изменения. Все гуд. Далее все логично. Вливаю эту ветку в продакшн (master) и в ветку разработки (develop). После чего ветка убивается.

И тут возникает закономерный момент при merge'e. Все файлы типа измененных .gitignore, включенных в коммит (и соответственно в индекс) файлов разработки типа .less и js-исходников, попадают в индекс ветки master (продакшн).

Как разграничить, сделать так чтобы файлы разработки при слиянии не попадали в ветку продакшена???

P.S. Пробовал вариант с no-commit, но тех же файлов less более 300...ручками исключать как-то неправильно...

Как решить сею проблему, пожалуйста, разъясните, помогите!
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: @scorp24, я уже по-моему говорил про это, что это вообще задача не VCS. Но если хотите, то можете воспользоваться [гит-хуками](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git) и написать скрипт, который будет фильтровать всё автоматически.

Продакшен из репозитория не должен быть готовым к запуску. Он должен быть готовым к *установке*.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. А как быть с файлами например конфигов, которые индексируются в обоих ветках, но эти конфиги должны оставаться в своих ветках?!

Comment: Вобщем я все непрвильно истолковал. Сборку надо осуществлять сторонними продуктами, типа нода или гулпа. А не только деплоем git'a. Спасибо за комментарий!

Answer (score 2):

В общем VCS нужна для разработки, поэтому держите там всё, что требуется в разработке. Как из этого опубликовать/развернуть/установить проект - вопрос вне системы контроля версий.

Возможно, есть несколько подходов. Опишу свой на примере одного из проектов.

Мастер, как уже написал [@Etki](/users/16095/etki), содержит файлы для установки (deploy) на рабочие сервера. Есть скрипт, который запускается после `pull`'а из origin master, который из репо публикует проект.

В моём проекте скрипт убирает на лету `console.log()`, оптимизирует JS/CSS — и наполняет заново папку public, которая **не** находится под контролем git, и из которой раздаются файлы проекта веб-сервером. Этот же скрипт командой `sed` корректирует некоторые конфиг файлы, чтобы точно выключить debug режим и пр.

Хорошо бы туда же включить финальные-финальные тесты, которые точно должны пройти, прежде чем таки выкатывать новую версию. Туда же можно зарядить сброс кэша и пр. подготовку. Скрипт этот можно запускать вручную, можно повесить на хук git'а.

Такая система деплоя довольно кустарна, но в описываемом маленьком проекте вполне достаточна.

Этот проект построен на Laravel. Там [можно](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration) задавать варианты конфигурационных параметров, в зависимости от окружения. У меня настроены два: Production и Development – определяется переменной, которую устанавливает веб-сервер, либо вручную параметром из командной строки для CLI-скриптов.

Comment: sergiks, спасибо!
Начал копать в этом направлении. Вариант рассматриваю такой. В удаленном репозитории хранится dev и master. По хуку изменения ветки мастера создается архив репозитория с последними изменениями, они же финальные (релизные), в гиатрибутах прописываются файлы на исключение из архива export-ignore. Далее архив выкатывается на site_root. Как-то так мне это видится в данный момент, если максимально просто. Но подозреваю, что есть более профессиональные решения для сборки проектов, ибо люблю порядок и прозрачность в проектировании.

Comment: @scorp24

> Но подозреваю, что есть более профессиональные решения для сборки проектов

capistrano (сам пока так и не познакомился, но это де-факто стандарт для развертывания, причем не только руби-приложений). Для проектов на Symfony есть [capyfony](http://capifony.org/).
Также довольно популярен [phing](http://www.phing.info/) (опять-таки не трогал), последний можно подключить плагином к PHPCI.

Answer (score 1):

У меня обычно 2 ветки - master, dev
master содержит в себе код, готовый к выполнению на боевом сервере. Работоспособный и оттестированный.
dev - содержит код, в котором возможны ошибки, из этой ветки мы вываливаем код на тестовый сервер для тестов.

Если я пилю какую то фичу, то делаю ответвление от dev ветки, называю новую фетку feat-<feature_short_name>, и в ней реализую эту фичу. Тестирую у себя. Если все классно, мержу эту ветку с dev веткой и отправляю на тестовый сервер. Если тесты проведены успешно, мержу dev с master, и обновляю боевые сервера.

Конфиги у меня сразу в 2 вариантах - dev, production для дев-окружения, и для боевых серверов соответственно.

Comment: > делаю ответвление от dev ветки, называю новую фетку feat-<feature_short_name>

посмотрите такую штуку, как git-flow (если не вообще именно о ней и говорите)